# About HAVING statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, having

I want to do something like this in a query.

```
GROUP BY act.date, d.causedat, x, y, z...
HAVING  MAX(act.date_) OVER (PARTITION BY act.date_ <= d.causedat)
```

Is this possible in some way?

I'm trying to reduce multiple returning rows to a single return based on the maximum date of act.date_ that's below d.causedat (both are dates in the same format)

Currently, doing a simple `select max(act.date_) where act.date_ <= d.causedat` isn't giving me single results, but clusters of different results, but i really just want the first (latest dated) one listed.

Edit for extra clarity:

Going in are 48 tables, joined together by a union, supplying a large amount of events and timestamps. Waiting for this data is a 200 line total select statement with a further 10 joins. I'm joining the union of joins to this table by looking at the maximum timestamp in the unions that takes place before the timestamp in my smaller select statement. Think of it like this. Lets assume i'm trying to match the row to the date 2012/01/01/1233.

```
date_            -   event            - event id
2012/01/01/1230 |    1#1#foo          |  1
2012/01/01/1231 |    2#1#foo#bar      |  1
2012/01/01/1232 |    1#1#foo#bar#etc  |  1
```

Only the last one is relevant to me, so i'm looking for the `max(date_)`.

On the other hand I have a table that lists the `causedat`, the date that I want to take and compare with the `max(date_)`, I want to take this date and then take the `date_` that's directly proceding it.

The results would then look like this:

```
x    -    y    -  event            -    date_           - causedat
info -    info -  1#1#foo#bar#etc  -    2012/01/01/1232 - 2012/01/01/1233
```

My question to all this is: Can it be done with a group by/having statement.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you could provide sample input data and the expected result you're trying to get. It's not immediately obvious from your question, and if we have to guess at your meaning, we're going to waste both our time and yours.

Comment: This should make it a little more obvious.

Comment: So you're after the row with the max date_ that's less than or equal to the causedat?

Comment: Indeed. I know this can be done with a select - from - where, but by using Group-by and Having, i'm getting it done in 15 seconds instead of 300+. The problem is, I'm not able to pick "single" rows per ID with `HAVING (max(act.date_) <= d.causedat)`, so is it possible to do this as in the first codeblock of my initial post?

Comment: aha, so you want per id?

Comment: id and causedat would always be unique by virtue of the timestamp (it goes into the milliseconds), so yeah, essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after the row with the biggest date prior to or on a specified date per event id, then perhaps this is what you're after:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('2012/01/01/1230', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24mi') date_, '1#1#foo' event, 1 event_id from dual union all
                     select to_date('2012/01/01/1231', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24mi') date_, '2#1#foo#bar' event, 2 event_id from dual union all
                     select to_date('2012/01/01/1232', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24mi') date_, '1#1#foo#bar#etc' event, 1 event_id from dual union all
                     select to_date('2012/01/01/1234', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24mi') date_, '5#1#foo#bar#etc#etc' event, 1 event_id from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table with your sample_data in it
select date_,
       event,
       event_id
from   (select date_,
               event,
               event_id,
               row_number() over (partition by event_id order by date_ desc) rn
        from   sample_data
        where  date_ <= to_date('2012/01/01/1233', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24mi'))
where  rn = 1;

DATE_             EVENT                 EVENT_ID
----------------- ------------------- ----------
2012/01/01/1232 1#1#foo#bar#etc              1
2012/01/01/1231 2#1#foo#bar                  2
```

Comment: Oracle only allows me a maximum of 1000 results using this method, does this happen to you as well?

Comment: What do you mean, a maximum of 1000 results? Did you get an error? If so, what's the exact error message? I've never seen that before with this type of query. (You do realise that you ignore the "with sample_data as ..." clause, which I just used to create some dummy data to run the query against, right?).

Comment: Yeah. I realize you are using the sample data. But Oracle sqldeveloper limits me to 1000 rows when I use the subselection on my own data, Which is odd. There's no error involved either, it works fine, and then it won't give me more then 1000 rows. Does it have anything to do with using the expression?

Comment: Are there more than 1000 rows to return?

Comment: Yeah... I'm counting over 1300.

Comment: Maybe SQL Developer is set to fetch the first 1000 records, and you need to do ctrl+end on the result set or something. It sounds like a SQL Developer issue, though.

Comment: Regardless of what my SQL Developer client is doing, this seems to be working for me. Thanks for the time and effort! Still unsure about my question about HAVING and OVER, though.

Comment: You can't use an analytic function in the having clause like that since the analytic function works over the final result set, and the WHERE/HAVING clauses filter the results returned, so the analytic query would end up changing which rows were filtered, which would affect its output, which would end up changing which rows were filtered etc etc. Best to calculate the analytic function first in a subquery and then use that calculated column to filter in the outer query - which is what I did in my answer. In short, no, it's not possible to use HAVING and OVER in the same clause..

Answer (score 0):

Check LAST_VALUE or FIRST_VALUE functions in Oracle.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm

There are dificult in use, but probably they will solve your problem. My example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT x, y, z, 
      LAST_VALUE(date1)
      OVER (PARTITION BY x,y,z ORDER BY date2 range between current row and unbounded following) my_date1,
      FROM table
) group by x,y,z,my_date1
```

If you paste your whole select I can help you with statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what your trying to do.
Sounds like you want both group by and rank the results.
Maybe this will help:

```
select * from (
    select act.date, d.causedat, x, y, z, max(act.date_),
     row_number() over (PARTITION BY act.date, d.causedat, x, y, z order by act.date_ DESC) as num_rank
     from TABLE 
     where act.date_ <= d.causedat
     group by ct.date, d.causedat, x, y, z
 ) where num_rank = 1
```